# How do I isolate the root path to turn on and off its 'active class' on the navbar?

Tags: django

I am hoping to better understand the urlpatterns in Django as well as figuring out this puzzle:

To turn the current page's link on the navbar to be `active` (ie, highlighted, as in `class="nav-item active"`, I use `{% if 'somelink' in request.path %}`, which mostly works.

But `{% if '/' in request.path %}` doesn't work for the homepage. The "Home" link remains highlighted whether or not one is on the page. Is it because all paths must go through `path('/' ...)`? How does one isolate the root url then?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use `{% if request.path == '/' %}` for the homepage, since you only want to highlight it when the user is on that exact page?

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask the question right: I only want 'Home' highlighted on the navbar if a user is on the homepage. Right now, with the code `{% if request.path == '/' %}`, the 'Home' link on the navbar is highlighted regardless of which page the user is on. So my question is: How do I make it highlighted ONLY when the user is on the homepage.

Comment: `{% if request.path == '/' %}` should only match when the user is on homepage/root. Can you add the section of your template that renders the homepage link to your question?

Comment: The entire navbar section is too long here: ```<!-- language-all: lang-html -->``` ```<li {% if '/' in request.path %}  <br/>
        class="nav-item active mr-3" <br/>
     {% else %} <br/>
        class="nav-item mr-3"
      {% endif %}>
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
        </li>

          <li {% if 'books' in request.path %}
          class="nav-item active mr-3"
        {% else %}
          class="nav-item mr-3"
        {% endif %}>
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'books' %}">All Books</a>
          </li>`

Comment: Took too long to tweak it and got locked out. But here it is: https://codepen.io/codebyline/pen/poNVwax